# Don't including class header when only declaration exists

Tags: c++, c++11, include, declaration, forward-declaration

I have the following case:

**class_a.hpp:**

```
#include "class_b.hpp" // is this "include" mandatory?
class class_a{
private:
    class_b b;
};
```

**class_a.cpp:**

```
#include "class_b.hpp"
//code that uses member variables and functions from class_b
```

**class_b.hpp:**

```
class class_b{};
```

Is it possible to get rid of `#include "class_b.hpp"` in the `class_a.hpp`? Since it is just declaration, why I can not just use forward declaration and not including it? (I tried but it was not compiled)

Of Course I have included `class_b.hpp` in the `class_a.cpp`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `class_b` needs to be stored inside `class_a` without any indirection *(e.g. a pointer)*, the size of `class_b` needs to be known during the declaration of `class_a`. In order to know the size, the declaration of `class_b` needs to be available: the `#include` directive is therefore required.

Comment: Silly me.. this should be obvious. many thanks

Comment: @HumamHelfawi If this is the answer to your question, you should accept it.

Comment: @PeterK Yes sure :) it needs time before it is allowed to accept it

Answer (score 3):

> why I can not just use forward declaration and not including it?

With only forward declaration the class type `class_b` will be [incomplete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type). But to be declared as a non-static class data member, need it to be complete, the size and layout of it must be know.

> Any of the following contexts requires class `T` to be complete:
>
> ```
> ...
> declaration of a non-static class data member of type `T`;
> ...
> ```
>
> (In general, when the size and layout of `T` must be known.)